# Difficulty returning junks in my C++ stack implementation

Tags: c++, stack, valgrind

I have implemented a stack in C++, but I have a problem with returning junks.
For example, I have:

```
...

template<class T>
T stack<T>::pop()
{
    /* Verific dacă există elemente pe stivă */
    if( isEmpty() )
    {
        T junk;
        fprintf(stderr, "No data.\n");
        return junk;
    }

    ...

}
```

This is not the right way for solving the problem, because I will have a valgrind error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is poor idea because (among other things) if `T`'s copy constructor can throw, it can destroy data (removes item from stack, then copying to return the item throws, which destroys the copy).

One way to fix the problem is to change the interface to something like this:

```
void stack<T>::pop(T &ret) { 
    if (!isempty())
        ret = data[top--];
}
```

Or, to provide an indication of whether it succeeded:

```
bool stack<T>::pop(T &ret) { 
    if (isempty())
        return false;
    ret = data[top];
    --top;
    return true;
}
```

This way, if the copy constructor throws, `top` is never decremented, so the item remains on the stack. If execution gets past that, the rest of the function can't throw, so we always either succeed completely (the item is copied to the proper destination and removed from the stack) or else the function has no effect at all (the item remains on the stack).

Comment: or possibly return a `T*` and `nullptr` if it's empty?

Comment: @dwcanillas: That's possible, but tends to be ugly--you're pretty much stuck with dynamically allocating everything, and leaving it up to the caller to destroy the object when they're finished with it.